# Checking if value in twodimensional array is equal to a "#"

Tags: c++, arrays

I have an array that gets populated by either a "." or a "#", and I need a way of checking whether `array[y+1][x]` is equal to `#`, do something if it is and stop the loop, otherwise increment `y`. First I wrote it without the & before `lavirint` and it gave me an error that it can't compare a pointer and an `int`, which got me confused cause "#" shouldn't be an `int`?

The problem is the first condition in the loop never happens although it should, and the loop stops when

```
y==n
```

Maybe I'm just stupid and overlooked something but I would really appreciate a solution to this.

```
char lavirint[500][500];

for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
{
    for (int j = 1; j <= m; j++)
    {
        scanf("%c", &lavirint[i][j]);
    }
}
bool n_povecava = true;
```

...

```
while(n_povecava)
    {
        if(&lavirint[y+1][x] == "#" || y==n)
        {
            k--;
            m_povecava = true;
            n_povecava = false;
        }
        else
            y++;
    }
```

Comment: _`for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)`_ Arrays are indexed from `0` to `N-1` where `N` is the size.

Comment: Should not you use _lavirint[y+1][x]_ instead _&lavirint[y+1][x]_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"#"` is a string literal of type `const char[2]` and decays to `const char*`.

You need `'#'` which is a character:

```
if (lavirint[y+1][x] == '#' || ... )
```